# in navigateurl how can i give width and height in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Hi when i am trying to give windth and height to a window through navigateUrl method its not opening my code`var js:String = "window.open(http://[Domain]/Project/pages/sample.jsp,'win','height=608,width=999');";
     var urlReqest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" +js + " void(0);");
     navigateToURL(urlReqest,"_blank");`
its not opnening,and if i give url is normal url means max window is opening.i want to open like width and height,
please help in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ExternalInterface for that. It allows you to call Javascript from Flex. An example of what you need can be found here:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Popup_a_window_without_getting_blocked_by_popup_bl-5221.html

Comment: Hi Pbirkoff, Thanks for your valuable suggestion it is working but one problem I am facing .it is very critical to me. When I am posting one value to jsp.with urlVariables through method=POST values are not getting in jsp, null values getting please help in this,if i use any different way it wil work or i can not post values like using http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Popup_a_window_without_getting_blocked_by_popup_bl-5221.html
sample code?